# What are these “Power Events:” > “Next Scheduled Events:” that are showing up in my macOS system information?

Tags: macos, power, catalina

I am running macOS Catalina Public Beta 9 (10.15, 19A573a) on my MacBook Air (2019) and noticed these — at least to my eyes — odd entries under “Hardware > Power” when looking at system information. FWIW, I don’t recall ever seeing these under “Hardware > Power” when running macOS Mojave (10.14):

```
Power Events:

  Next Scheduled Events:

    appPID: 353
    Type:   Wake
    Scheduled By:   com.apple.alarm.user-invisible
    Time:   10/6/19, 6:27 AM
    UserVisible:    0

    appPID: 356
    Type:   Wake
    Scheduled By:   com.apple.alarm.user-invisible
    Time:   10/6/19, 7:47 AM
    UserVisible:    0
```

I have utterly no alarms or power events that I have set on my Mac and double checking under “Energy Saver” as well as my calendar shows nothing as well. And besides, I would never set up crazy early morning alarms like this anyway.

Is this something connected to me using macOS Catalina Public Beta? Since November 6th seems to be the date macOS Catalina will come out of beta.

FWIW, checking my running processes right now I see the following for those `appPID` values:

```
501   356 ??         0:03.06 /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (Aqua)
501   353 ??         0:02.74 /usr/sbin/cfprefsd agent
```

Found some info on [`cfprefsd` on this Other World Computing post](https://blog.macsales.com/45408-seeing-cfprefsd-and-cloudd-should-you-be-exorcising-macs-hidden-daemons/) and [`UserEventAgent` on this How-To Geek post](https://www.howtogeek.com/338994/what-is-usereventagent-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-mac/). And the information is useful as to literally what these processes do, but no real explanation as to why they are set in this case.

Comment: I'm running High Sierra and they show up on my machine.  Same type as yours.

Comment: Is you Mac managed?

Answer (score 0):

you can use terminal command:

```
sudo pmset schedule cancelall
```

Then you can resolve it

Comment: Unfortunately, while this will kill the next event, the rest repopulate themselves. I'm not sure how. Some kind of launchdaemon which respawns and repopulates the wake events every 24 hours (maximum).