# How can I check for Power Nap event history?

Tags: macos, catalina, power-management

I'd like to see when my Mac is waking up with [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204032). How can I check the event history to see when Power Nap is causing my Mac to wake up? Especially interested in wake-up events while on battery power.

I'm using macOS 10.15 Catalina.

Comment: Have you seen console app? or logs https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371285/what-are-these-power-events-next-scheduled-events-that-are-showing-up-in?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374754/my-computer-wakes-up-at-55939-every-morning-how-do-i-stop-that-from-happening?rq=1 and almost every question which says that MacBook doesnt sleep/ or MacBook wakes up.